# How to make code dynamic removing hard coded values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I have an array of data which has corporation names based in their respective countries. I have also filtered out based on the country name, but, hard coded values aren't required. So, what could be the best optimal solution, to make code dynamic

Following is the code for reference

1. Home.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DetailComp from "./DetailComp";


const Home = () => {

  const data = [
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA" , corpName:"USA Brad"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA" , corpName:"USA Bayker"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN" , corpName:"Canada Zyphus"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA" , corpName:"USA Hamilton"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN" , corpName:"Canada Sterling"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN" , corpName:"Canada Stones"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA" , corpName:"USA Global Exchange"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA" , corpName:"USA Wrights"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "GERMANY" , corpName:"German Moto"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "GERMANY" , corpName:"German Wines"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "GERMANY" , corpName:"German Plastics"} },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN" , corpName:"Canada Electronics"} }
  ];

  const [newData, setNewData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewData(data)
  }, [])

  const usData = newData.filter(item => item.country.cntryShortName === "USA")
  const canData = newData.filter(item => item.country.cntryShortName === "CAN")
  return <>
  <DetailComp data={usData}  />
  <DetailComp data={canData} />
  </>;
};

export default Home;
```

2. DetailComp.js

```
const DetailComp = (props) => {
  console.log("PROPS", props.data)
  return <>
  {
    props.data.map(data => (
      <h2>{data.country.corpName}</h2>
    ))
  }
  </>;
};

export default DetailComp;
```

As you can see in the Home component I'm trying to filter out the array data based on country name which I'm hard coding it and not expected. Is there any better solution to make the code dynamic?

Please refer codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-cache-4ks1ml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group data by country and then use that grouped data to display

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import DetailComp from "./DetailComp";

//group countries by short name
const groupCountries = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((result, item) => {
    const { country: { cntryShortName } } = item;

    if(!result[cntryShortName]) {
      result[cntryShortName] = [];
    }

    result[cntryShortName].push(item);

    return result;
  }, {})
}

const Home = () => {
  const data = [
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Brad" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Bayker" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Zyphus" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Hamilton" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Sterling" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Stones" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Global Exchange" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Wrights" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "GERMANY", corpName: "German Moto" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "GERMANY", corpName: "German Wines" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "GERMANY", corpName: "German Plastics" } },
    { country: { cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Electronics" } }
  ];

  const [newData, setNewData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    //set new data with grouped countries
    setNewData(groupCountries(data));
  }, []);

  //render grouped data
  return (
    <>
      {Object.entries(newData).map(([key, value]) => <DetailComp data={value} key={key}/>)}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-heisenberg-oxzqpu?file=/src/Home.js:0-1563)

Comment: Nice solution... only one concern. How to club data based on country like for USA all its relevant data would be populated similarly for Canada? To explain in detail for USA separate component whereas for Canada another component

Comment: Maybe need to make changes in DetailComp file

Comment: you can try to use `key` in `newData`  to set conditional renderings based on countries :D @PrakashPatil

Comment: If you don't mind can you please update it on your sandbox

Comment: Just for understanding, you want to have a filter for each country? @PrakashPatil